# I Want to Automatically Modifiy Release date when I build it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, release, installshield

I am using visual studio 2010 to develop a desktop application ; however , the date of release is very important , so every time I build a release to produce a setup (.exe) using InstallSheild for my application . I have to modify the release date manually. Most of the times , I forgot to edit it which make me duplicate the work and build the release and produce another setup with correct release date

I Googled , but All I could things talks about version number;Nevertheless ,I put the code below to  demonstrate the idea

```
 DateTime ReleaseDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 06, 09);
            _ReleaseDate = ReleaseDateTime.ToString("d", culture);
            _CopyRight = MLanguageContext.Instance.Translate(MyoLanguageIds.RightsReservedId.ToString(), "© 2019 all rights reserved");
```

I expect the ReleaseDate time to be updated automatically with every release build I make from visual studio

Comment: What type of setup project do you have?

Comment: I am using Installshield to produce my setup and my project based on .Net4.0 and WPF

Comment: What "Release Date" are you trying to change?  Is that something in the InstallShield project or the the .EXE?  Are you using Jenkins or some other tool for the build of the EXE and Install?

Comment: This is essentially what build pipelines like Jenkins, Teamcity, etc. are designed to do, look into one of them. If you build this manually, then you have to alter the date manually

Comment: The process I follow is that . I build my project using normal visual studio 2010 build . then I took the files produced from built to Installsheild to produce setup (.exe)

@Liam I will check them out